# Facebook Open Graph - Custom link for image - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application is very image centric and would like to allow the user to share images generated by the application on facebook posts.  I am of the understanding that "User Generated" can only be used with user/camera taken photos so that is not an option. Correct?

Since I can't specify user generated, I'd like to either:

1. Set the link on the feed image such that the image in the album is opened, not the default og:url.

   - This link is by default the og:url specified in the open graph object.
   - I still need all of the other og:url links in the post except the image to point to the website page.

     ```
                      -OR-
     ```
2. Put an href link in the description (or somewhere else in the feed post) that opens the image in the album.

   - Unless I am mistaken, It doesn't seem that HTML href tags are allowed in posts/stories.  Is there a way to do this in the caption of a custom story?

I am able to upload the image to the app's album and obtain the URL to the image in the album (also using "no story" so that it doesn't create a post).

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

How do I garner more control over the links set in a facebook feed post?

EDIT:
Regarding "User Generated" from [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/#actioncapabilities):
"The User Generated Photos action capability can only be used if the photos are original and taken by a user with an actual camera."

I don't want to generate two stories.  Ideally I want ONE story that features an image that can be clicked on that links to the original full size image in the app album.  The rest of the story shares some details about the image (desc. etc.).  So I guess, in a way, I'm looking for a workaround for the camera/photo requirement.

I don't mind the standard story layout (with a smaller image with title, description/captions) but just want to link that image to one in the users application album.

EDIT:
I'm realizing that an Open Graph Story isn't the way to go here. I have instead gone to simply using the Graph API. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) This allows me to post a link in the user comments along with a photo.  For anyone interested:

```
public static void doImagePost(final Bitmap _sideBySide, String _comments) {

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putParcelable("image", _sideBySide);

    String message;
    if(_comments != null)
    {

        if(!_comments.isEmpty())
        {
            message = _comments + '\n' + '\n' + JSBridge.getURL();
        } else {
            message = JSBridge.getURL();  
        }
    } else {
        message = JSBridge.getURL();
    }
//Plain Http://blahblahblah.com/foobar/whatever gets turned into a link in the message field
    parameters.putString("message", message);

    Bitmap redSideBySide = EHelper.reduceImageSize(_sideBySide, (int)4E6);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session == null) {
        requestPublish(MODE_PHOTO, redSideBySide, _comments);
        return;
    } else {
        if(!session.isOpened())
        {
            requestPublish(MODE_PHOTO, redSideBySide, _comments);
            return;
        }
    }

//Here is the Graph API request.
    Request imagePostRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos" , parameters, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if(response.getError() == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(m_Context, "Post image success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //m_Images = null;
                dismissProgressDlg();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(m_Context, "Error posting image to facebook: " + response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Error posting image to facebook: " + response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                dismissProgressDlg();
            }
        }
    });

    showProgressDialog("Posting to Facebook...");
    imagePostRequest.executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` I am of the understanding that "User Generated" can only be used with user/camera taken photos so that is not an option. Correct?` And I cant understand why are you creating 2 stories for one action- `photo` and `feed`

Comment: See, its a very broad ques.. :-/

Comment: Hopefully the edits above make it a bit more clear?

Comment: You're saying that on click on the feed, the link to image in facebook will be opened. That means the image is already uploaded to an album? Sorry its very unclear

Comment: Also, to make you clear, facebook dont allow to post a facebook link such as `facebook.com/XXXX` in a feed.

Comment: I'm realizing that an Open Graph Story isn't the way to go here.  I have instead gone to simply using the Graph API.  This allows me to post a link in the user comments along with a photo.